# Ошибка Resources$NotFoundException

Tags: android

Прохожу обучение по курсу Android, в одном из заданий возникла проблема, в чём, не понимаю. Скорее всего что-то не так с текстовыми файлами, в  ресурсах.

```
package com.example.opimand.manul5;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.WebView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class DetailActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        //получаем строку и формируем имя ресурса
        String resName = "n" + intent.getIntExtra("head", 0);
        Log.i("name", resName);
        Context context = getBaseContext(); //получаем контекст

        //читаем текстовый файл из ресурсов по имени
        String text = readRawTextFile(context, getResources().getIdentifier(resName, "raw", "ru.alexanderklimov.manual"));

        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, text, "text/html", "en_US", null);
    }

    //читаем текст из raw-ресурсов
    public static String readRawTextFile(Context context, int resId){
        InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(resId);

        InputStreamReader inputReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(inputReader);
        String line;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            while (( line = buffReader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
                builder.append("\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

Вот код ошибки:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.opimand.manul5, PID: 3325
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.opimand.manul5/com.example.opimand.manul5.DetailActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
        Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
            at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:190)
            at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.openRawResource(ResourcesImpl.java:298)
            at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResource(Resources.java:1239)
            at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResource(Resources.java:1184)
            at com.example.opimand.manul5.DetailActivity.readRawTextFile(DetailActivity.java:40)
            at com.example.opimand.manul5.DetailActivity.onCreate(DetailActivity.java:32)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема заключается в строке

> String text = readRawTextFile(context, getResources().getIdentifier(resName, "raw", "ru.alexanderklimov.manual"));

Заместо `ru.alexanderklimov.manual` вам необходимо прописать `package`, в котором расположены ваши ресурсы.

К примеру, так:

```
String text = readRawTextFile(context, getResources().getIdentifier(resName,
"raw", "com.example.opimand.manul5"));
```

**Объяснение:**

Вы пытаетесь найти ресурсы, расположенные по пути `ru.alexanderklimov.manual`, хотя в вашем проекте нет такого пути. Так как *Android* не может найти ресурсы, он бросает `NotFoundException`.